# Optimization of a SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN without index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL request that produce a view on my SQL Server that I need to optimize :

```
SELECT some_stuff 
FROM some_table 
INNER JOIN another_table
       ON some_condition
LEFT OUTER JOIN third_table
       ON third_table.responsetype = another_table.eventcode
WHERE  ( another_table.externalsystemreferenceid <> '' )
```

From the execution plan in SQL server, it is the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that takes much of the time (83%).

My first idea was to put an index on `another_table.eventcode` (there is already one on `third_table.responsetype`) but this table is frequently updated and the cost of having to update an index very often is probably not worth it.

So I have two questions :

- Is there a way to optimize the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` without index and how ?
- (*A more theorical one to better understand index*) Let's say I want to use index without regard to the impact, on which part should I put it and why ?

  - `ON third_table.responsetype = another_table.eventcode` (on which one? both?) ?
  - or `WHERE  ( another_table.externalsystemreferenceid <> '' )` ?

Thanks in advance for any response,

Answer (score 1):

You could use a composite  index on table  another_table

```
columns  (  eventcode, externalsystemreferenceid )
```

and you should also add to the composite index  also   the another_table  column that are involved in your  JOIN another_table
       ON some_condition

Answer (score 1):

The indexes that you want are:

- `thirdtable(responsetype, . . . )` -- the `. . .` is for the other referenced columns
- `anothertable(externalsystemreferenceid, eventcode . . )`

The second index is probably not helpful, unless almost all the values are blank in `anothertable`.

You should check to see if the index updates on `thirdtable` are expensive.  If this is an issue, you may need two copies of your database -- one for transaction processing and another for queries such as the one you want to implement.

Comment: thanks for the reply, just to be clear, by "second index" you mean an index on `externalsystemreferenceid` ? why would it not be helpful on `eventcode` ?

Comment: @DaveSmith . . . Because most rows probably pass the `WHERE` condition.